# Software for making advanced custom fonts

Tags: font, photoshop

I want to make an unuque font in details and import it to photoshop, i know that there is a feature called match font but it's not very specific for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at [FontForge](https://fontforge.github.io)?  It's probably far beyond what you need in terms of what it can do, but they've got pretty good documentation, the fonts it generates are usable pretty much anywhere, and it's also free.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it suits my needs, even above.